# How can I unserialize data from database after it was serialized

Tags: sql, arrays, session

```
try {
    if (isset($_SESSION['list']) > 0) {         
        $test = serialize($_SESSION["list"]);
        $sQuery = "INSERT INTO table (id, date) VALUES ('$test', NOW())";
        $oStmt = $db->prepare($sQuery); 
        $oStmt->execute();
    }
    else {
        echo 'No data';
    }
}
```

In my database I see this:

```
1   a:1:{i:1;s:1:"5";}  2011-12-21
```

The $_SESSION['list'] stores ID and the QUANTITY.

The data a:1:{i:1;s:1:"5";} is as follow: i=id, s=id:"quantity", I read this as id=1 and the quantity of id=1 is 5, am I correct?

Now I want select the data and unserialize the array.

```
try {
    $sQuery = "SELECT * FROM table"; 
    $oStmt = $db->prepare($sQuery);
    $oStmt->execute();

    while($aRow = $oStmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $id = unserialize($aRow['id']);

        foreach($id as $id => $quantity) {  

            echo $id.', ';
        }
    }
}

catch(PDOException $e) { 
    $sMsg = '<p> 
    Regelnummer: '.$e->getLine().'<br /> 
    Bestand: '.$e->getFile().'<br /> 
    Foutmelding: '.$e->getMessage().' 
    </p>'; 
    trigger_error($sMsg); 
}
```

What am I doing wrong or what can I do so I can select the ID and QUANTITY from database?

Answer (score 0):

The serialization/deserialization part looks fine to me, but the `$oStmt->fetchALL(` I think should be `$oStmt->fetch(`, and in `foreach($id as $id => $quantity) {` use another variable to hold the key instead of id, like `foreach($id as $key => $quantity) {`.

Also, you don't echo the quantity anywhere. Change `echo $id.', ';` to `echo $key.' '.$quantity;` or something and tell us what the output is so we can help further.

Comment: Thank you, it was verry helpfull. I changed $oStmt->fetchAll( to $oStmt->fetch( and changed foreach($id as $id => $quantity) { to foreach($id as $key=> $quantity) { and the result was exactlly what i needed. Thank you again.